# Best approach for this iOS XML parsing case

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser

I want to turn this XML:

```
<tennis>
<date>01-01-2013
<tournament>
<location>
<city>London</city>
<venue>Wimbledon</venue>
</location>
<match>
<player>Andy Murray</player>
<player>Roger Federer</player>
</match>
<match>
<player>Rafa Nadal</player>
<player>Andy Roddick</player>
</match>
</tournament>

<date>02-01-2013
<tournament>
<location>...
```

Into a tableview showing the dates, which when selected will then navigate to a grouped tableview, with the Venue as section header, and a list of matches in the table rows.

My question is what's the best approach. Currently I'm using NSXMLParser to..

- create a dictionary, with each Date being the key for an array of Venues.
- create Match objects, and store an array of Match against each Venue in a dictionary.

then my first tableview is just displays the keys from the Date dictionary, and when a row is selected it 'passes' the associated array of Venues to the next tableview class..

which then selects out the Match objects from the 2nd dictionary, using the passed-in array of Venues as the key to find.

Apologies if that's confusing, it is to me when I write it out.

- Is this NSXMLParser method of building up arrays and dictionaries, setting flags to keep state etc, the recommended method for an XML like mine?
- Should I be using a DOM parser?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If it works, don't modify it, it's not worth it. NSXMLParser is - surprise, surprise - suited for parsing XML. Don't bother using external DOM parser libraries, whatever.

Comment: thanks, can I trouble you.. if you were faced with that xml and desired output, would you go about it the same way I am?

Comment: see, there's no real difference between XML and XML... as long as it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this xml parser:

[SMXMLDocument](https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument)

It makes the xml into nice arrays or dictionaries for you to use

Answer (score 0):

I use `XSXMLparser` to parse some XML from a website then display the Keys in a table via:

```
[myDictionary allKeys]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row;
```

Then on selection i create a new instance of the table and set the important variables through properties:

```
tableScreen *tableScreenNew = [[tableScreen alloc]init];
            tableScreenNew.currentLevel = 1;
            tableScreenNew.numberOfRows = counter;
            tableScreenNew.parsedData = parsedData;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableScreenNew animated:YES];
```

This will push the new table with the data i need, and in the `cellForRow:` i just have an if:

```
if(currentLevel == 0)
{

}
else if(currentLevel == 1)
{

}
else
{
 NSLog(@"I Messed up");
}
```

And in the cellForRow assign a temporary dictionary to what you need so in your case:

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[originalParsedData valueForKey:dateKeyNameFromLastTable]];
```

EDIT:Parse Code

```
NSData *myData = [xmlToParse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myData];
    [parser setDelegate:self];

 if([parser parse])
    {
         NSLog(@"Success");
         NSLog(@"****************************** Finished Dictionary ******************************");
         for(int i = 0;i < [parsedData count];i++)
         {
             NSLog(@"%d:%@",i,[parsedData objectAtIndex:i]);
         }
         NSLog(@"*********************************************************************************");
     }
    else
    {
         NSLog(@"Epic Fail");
         NSLog(@"%@",[parser parserError]);
    }




   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
    NSLog(@"Processing Attributes: %@", attributeDict);

    //Here you would start adding the key/Dicts to a NSMutableDictionary which you would use to populate tables

[myNSMutableDictionary addObject:attributeDict forKey:elementName];
}
```